# Half of Slider is cut out upon rotating it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am setting up the basic layout for a new piece of software I am developing, I have the grid setup in a 2x2. The main section (0,0) is for a canvas, the bottom main (0,1) is space for a slider, let's call it Slider1 and finally the right main (1,0) is space for Slider2. The issue is I want Slider2 to be rotated along the Y axis giving sliders for both X & Y, upon rotating the slider the top and bottom get completely cut off and sometimes VS forces it to change column.

My XAML for the page is as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="600"/>
    <Slider Name="Slider2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="300">
        <Slider.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Slider.RenderTransform>
    </Slider>
</Grid>
```

And this shows on the WPF as:
[image: Image of resulting XAML]

As you can see Slider2 on the right is not displaying fully and the goal is just to have it display fully and be able to keep it in the column it's in with it being centred to it's Grid position.

I've been playing around for awhile and can't see to get it working, so I'm hoping one of you clever people can point out the simple mistake I've made.

Cheers for any help!

Comment: @Clemens No, I'm fairly new to WPF and was letting VS choose what to transform it with. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying a RenderTransform, set the Slider's `Orientation` property to `Vertical`:

```
<Slider x:Name="Slider2" Orientation="Vertical" ... />
```

Comment: This seems like a better idea than using RenderTransform, however this shows that the Transform was not the issue as setting Vertical orientation makes the whole slider disappear.

Comment: "makes the whole slider disappear", what does that mean?

Comment: None of it was visible at all, it wasn't just cut off, but I've sorted it, I still had a high width set from when I was transforming it. Now it is sorted, thank you very much. Any idea what caused my original issue so I can avoid it in the future?

Comment: Imagine how the layout would look like without the rotation, then only rotate the Slider without changing the layout. You should have set the LayoutTransform property instead of RenderTransform.